# how to set compressor for compressed wire transfer between mongodb atlas and spring application

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I try to set up the compression for the messages transferred between mongodb atlas cluster to spring application. I followed this link: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/tutorials/compression/. My connection string in spring is:

```
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb+srv://userName:password@xxxxxxx.mongodb.net/test?compressors=zlib&retryWrites=true&w=majority
      database: mydb
```

It does not let server compress the result to transfer. Looks I missed config on the server-side for the zlib compression. What should I do to enable this? Searched through MongoDB Atlas management pages, but could not find anywhere to set it up.